# Can not compile after migrating unified api in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin

We have migrated the xamarin forms project to unified api.
But we have the strange compile error like this:
Could not AOT the assembly '.../iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/Build/Xamarin.Forms.Labs.dll

So I changed the settings in iOS project's options.
In ios Build Tab of Project options(iOS) I changed the "don't link" to "Link all assemblies".
But the app is crashed when it is started.

xamarin version is 5.7.1(build 17).
xamarin forms's version is 1.3.5.6337.
xamarin forms labs's version is 1.0.1.5.

Please help me if you have the experience with this error.

Answer (score 0):

Replace Xamarin.Forms.Labs with XLabs.Forms.

There has been a major refactoring on how the XLabs project is structured so your existing project based on the 1.x.x will break. The reason for the refactoring was simple; separate functionality that does not depend on Xamarin.Forms into different assemblies. This allows the use of functionality like IoC, Serialization and even platform specific services without referencing XF.

To upgrade:

1. Uninstall any existing Xamarin.Forms.Labs packages from your
   project.
2. Install XLabs.Forms package to your projects (PCL, iOS, Droid & WP). This will update Xamarin.Forms to the latest stable release (1.4.x)
3. Refactor code to reference the correct namespaces.